# In SWI-Prolog is there an easy way to convert numbers from one base to another using REPL?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

In SWI-Prolog using the REPL, one can get easily convert from any base to base 10, e.g.

```
?- X = 16'FF.
X = 255.

?- X = 2'11111111.
X = 255.
```

However this fails. (Didn't expect it to work, but shows what I am thinking.)

```
?- 2'X = 16'FF.
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: 
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: 2'X = 16'FF .
```

Comment: This is an integer *literal*, but it is not an operator. Furthermore say this works, what should `X` be here? If it is a number, then the 2-representation of `X` is again 255.

Comment: yes, but what I mean is, what should be the *type* of `X` then? After all `2'11` is just a *representation* of the number `3`. So then `X` should be a *string*?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem OK. I wasn't planing on using it in code. Just wanted a quick way to change bases for values. I am writing test cases for the lexer and for the unprintable characters just wanted a quick way to see the other values. I am using an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) but thought why not see if the REPL could do it. Didn't know the answer so asked here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, you can use `r` for *radix* in [`format/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/2):

> Print integer in radix numeric argument notation. Thus ~16r prints its argument hexadecimal. The argument should be in the range [2, ... , 36]. Lowercase letters are used for digits above 9. The colon modifier may be used to form locale-specific digit groups.

Example:

```
?- format("~2r", 0xFF).
11111111
true.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment posted as an answer because it needs the formatting that comments can't do.

If you are interested in capturing the output to say an atom, string, chars or character codes for use in a program then there is an additional variation of *format/n* that can do this. See: [format/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/3)

```
?- format(atom(Hex),"~2r",0xFF).
Hex = '11111111'.

?- format(string(Hex),"~2r",0xFF).
Hex = "11111111".

?- format(chars(Hex),"~2r",0xFF).
Hex = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'].

?- format(codes(Hex),"~2r",0xFF).
Hex = [49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49].
```

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote, but it really is meant to be a comment. If you want to give it an up-vote, then vote up the question so it appears higher in the list.