# Convert Binary to decimal predicate

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, list

```
convertBinToDec(B,D):- atom_number(S,B),
                       atom_length(S,L),
                       sub_atom(S, 0, 1, After,S1),
                       atom_number(S1,N),
                       L1 is L-1,
                       sub_atom(S, 1,L1, After ,S2),
                       atom_number(S2,B2),
                       convertBinToDec(B2,D1),
                       D is D1+((2*N)**L1).
convertBinToDec(0,0).
convertBinToDec(1,1).
```

The predicate takes B which is Binary number in integer form and should return D its corresponding decimal form ,Sorry I am still new to declarative programming languages but I don't know why my code above is always giving false, I feel there is something wrong with base case Also it is not allowed to use prolog Libraries

Comment: Of interest: [In SWI-Prolog is there an easy way to convert numbers from one base to another using REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54297462/1243762)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `After` two times. Any usage of a variable in the clause can be instantiated to a only a single value. `After` cannot take two different values in two calls to the procedure `sub_atom`. This will work, try figuring out why?

```
convertBinToDec(B,D):- atom_number(S,B),
                       atom_length(S,L),
                       sub_atom(S, 0, 1, After,S1),
                       atom_number(S1,N),
                       sub_atom(S, 1, After, 0, S2),
                       atom_number(S2, B2),
                       convertBinToDec(B2,D1),
                       D is D1+((2*N)**(L-1)).
convertBinToDec(0,0).
convertBinToDec(1,1).
```

This is highly procedural thinking.

A more idiomatic prolog solution will be

```
conv([], 0).
conv([0|Xs], N) :-
    conv(Xs, N).
conv([1|Xs], N) :-
    conv(Xs, N1),
    length(Xs, L),
    N is 2**L + N1.

% To convert atoms to binary list
code_to_binary(48, 0).
code_to_binary(49, 1).

convAtom(B, D) :-
    atom_codes(B, C),
    maplist(code_to_binary, C, Bin),
    conv(Bin, D).
```

`conv/2` does most of the calculation. Partitioning data representation and core logic of the problem is always a good idea.

Examples:

```
?- conv([1, 0, 0, 1], X).
X = 9.

?- conv([0, 0, 1, 0 , 0, 0, 1], X).
X = 17

?- convAtom('1010', X).
X = 10.

?- convAtom('0010001', X).
X = 17.
```

Answer (score 6):

Given that Prolog supports expressing binary numbers using the `0b` prefix, e.g. `0b10011101`, you can use the standard `number_codes/2` predicate to perform the conversion:

```
convert_binary_to_decimal(Binary, Decimal) :-
    number_codes(Binary, Codes),
    number_codes(Decimal, [0'0, 0'b| Codes]).
```

Sample call:

```
| ?- convert_binary_to_decimal(10011101, Decimal).

Decimal = 157

yes
```

Verify the result:

```
| ?- Decimal is 0b10011101.

Decimal = 157

yes
```

Comment: Nice errors for invalid input like 2 or -1